# I lose variable values in a silverlight application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm pretty new to silverlight, I'm using silverlight to create a grid and populate it via WCF Service, the control is hosted in an ASP.net  page
there are some filtering controls in the asp page, I read them, pass them to silverlight control and store them in a variable to be passed to the wcf service, the problem is at some point the variable loses its value.
I debugged the application and found out that the event handler "Application_Exit" is called
I guess this happens because of a reloading of the control or something.
does anyone know how to get around this particular obstacle

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like your ASP.NET page is firing a post-back or possibly an ajax partial postback that is navigating the page or removing the Silverlight HTML object.  If this is the case, you'd have to alter the ASP.NET design to not navigate away or replace the Silverlight content.

Comment: that was exactly the problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating Silverlight with ASP.Net postback controls (assuming you have postback controls present) is a bad combination.

Your filters either need to be in the Silverlight app, or you need to use client-only Javascript to notify Silverlight of the changes. Make sure they are not posting back the page (as many ASP.Net controls do).

I would tend to migrate more (all?) into Silverlight as you don't have the control state issues. You then have a normal ASP.net page as the fallback if Silverlight is not installed.